# Windows Sharepoint services - stsadm - How to enable command line options

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to install a feature into a SharePoint site. I am trying to do it with the command prompt. When I open the command prompt and give the command like:

```
stsadm -o installfeature
```

It is saying that

```
'stsadm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to do this with the command prompt. Is it necessary to use powershell only? Do I need to change any environment variable?

Comment: I strongly suggest switching to the PowerShell cmdlets. stsadm is only included for backward compatiblity and might be removed in the next version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register the path of `'stsadm.exe'` in the path which as I can remember is here:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN`

or type in the following command:

`@set PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN;%PATH%`

Hope that helped.

Comment: I tired this one. But still is showing like that error only :(

Comment: Weird! it's suppose to work!
anyways try [This link](http://sharepointroot.com/2010/06/28/stsadm-make-it-easy/) or [This one](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/09/28/easy-access-to-stsadm-exe.aspx) or [this one](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/09/28/easy-access-to-stsadm-exe.aspx)

Comment: Can you please suggest more websites you suggested as above

Comment: I am glad it worked for you ^_^ 

Here some useful website [one](http://www.sharepointdoug.com/) [two](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/) [three](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/) and also, you can google sharepoint for some very interesting and good websites.

 Good luck!